# Changing background colour of the line at point

Tags: coloring

I would like to change the background colour of the line at point.  Would also like to be able to go back to the original colour.

Have used `hl-line-mode` to highlight the current line.  Is it possible for the mode to highlight a line or region permanently?  The possibility to loop through various colours would be of value too.

Basically I want to change the background colour of a line or region by iterating through a list of colours.  Something simple rather than using quite complicated code such as `highlight.el` of Drew.

Perhaps make a simple package just to change background colour through a number of hex codes using `highlight.el` as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hl-line-mode`.............

Comment: That highlights the current line.  Can it me made to highlight a particular line and keep it highlighted?

Comment: If you want that, you should include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `(global-hl-line-mode 1)` in your init, you should be able to see the current overlay with   `describe-char`:

> There is an overlay here:
>
> face    hl-line

Then it's just a matter of reading its background color with `face-attribute`. Here you can toggle between two colors a and b:

```
(defun toggle-hl-line ()
(interactive)
(let ((a "#d0691e") (b "black")
      (current-color (face-attribute 'hl-line :background)))
(cond ((string-equal current-color a)(set-face-background 'hl-line  b))
      ((string-equal current-color b)(set-face-background 'hl-line  a))
      (t (set-face-background 'hl-line  a)))))
```

You can see the available color names with `list-colors-display`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
$ emacs --version

GNU Emacs 29.0.50
Development version 53c0690fa28f on master branch; build date 2022-07-07.
```

1. Download https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el and put it under `~/src/elisp/highight.el`.
2. Copy the below snippet in to a file `~/highlight-line.el`

```lisp
;; Ability to highlight lines

;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el

(load-file "~/src/elisp/highlight.el")

(defvar hlt-highlight-line-direction 1)

(defun hlt-highlight-line (start end face msgp)
  (interactive
   (list (save-excursion (point-at-bol))
         (save-excursion (point-at-eol))
         nil
         t))
  (hlt-highlight-region start end face msgp)
  (forward-line hlt-highlight-line-direction))

(defun hlt-unhighlight-line (start end face msgp)
  (interactive (list (save-excursion (point-at-bol))
                     (save-excursion (point-at-eol))
                     nil
                     t))
  (hlt-unhighlight-region start end face msgp)
  (forward-line (* -1 hlt-highlight-line-direction)))

(defun hlt-highlight-toggle-line-direction ()
  (interactive)
  (setq hlt-highlight-line-direction
        (* -1 hlt-highlight-line-direction)))

(define-key hlt-map (kbd "l") 'hlt-highlight-line)
(define-key hlt-map (kbd "L") 'hlt-unhighlight-line)
(define-key hlt-map (kbd "X") 'hlt-highlight-toggle-line-direction)

;; (setq repeat-keep-prefix nil)

(defun make-keymap-repeatable (sym)
  (map-keymap
   (lambda (_key cmd)
     (when (symbolp cmd)
       (message "%-20s ->  `%S'" (single-key-description _key) cmd)
       (put cmd 'repeat-map sym)))
   (symbol-value sym))
  (repeat-mode -1)
  (repeat-mode 1))

(make-keymap-repeatable 'hlt-map)
```

4. `emacs -Q`
5. `C-x C-f highlight-line.el`
6. `M-x  eval-buffer <return>`
7. Do some highlights `C-x C-x X l  l  l  l  l  l`
8. Switch face with `n`
9. Do some more highights with `l  l  l  l  l  l`
10. Do some unhighights with `L  L  L  L  L`
11. Switch face with `n`
12. Do some more highlights with `l  l  l  l`
13. Move down few lines `<down>  <down>  <down>  <down>  <down>  <down>`
14. Start highlighting again with `C-x X l  l`.

This is what you will see

[image: Demo of highlight-line.el]

15. At the end if you want to remove all the highlights do `C-x X u r`.

---

You can repeat the above procedure by `eval`-ing the  below macro, and doing `M-x highlight-line-demo`

```lisp
(defalias 'highlight-line-demo
   (kmacro "<f11>  C-x C-f  h  i  g  h  l  i  g  h  t  -  l  i  n  e  .  e  l  <return>  M-x  e  v  a  l  -  b  u  f  f  e  r  <return>  C-x X l  l  l  l  l  l  n  l  l  l  l  l  l  L  L  L  L  L  n  l  l  l  l  <down>  <down>  <down>  <down>  <down>  <down>  C-x X l  l  C-x 3  M-x  v  i  e  w  -  l  o  s  s  a  g  e  <return> "))
```